PostgreSQL "ALL" vs "ALL PRIVILEGES"
In PostgreSQL what is the difference between
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM SCHEMA public;

vs
REVOKE ALL FROM SCHEMA public;


No difference. REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES syntax is required by SQL specification but grammatically redundant and PRIVILEGES word was made optional in postgresql.
Mentioned in GRANT documentation:

The PRIVILEGES key word is optional in PostgreSQL, though it is required by strict SQL.

